# Do I have inacurate blueprints?

Tags: image

Upon scaling these car blueprints in all views it turns out a bit longer in side view. In front, back and top view everything is ok though. Do I have inacurate blueprints or am I doing this wrong? I have added images.

[image]

Comment: I tried to upload images but it appears i can only upload one.

Comment: Hi :). The blueprint doesn't seem to be very precise. Even when you rotate the top view - hood length and wheel wells size doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you for replying.